# jQuery strip HTML all forms

Tags: jquery

I want to have a generic .js file which, for each `form` it encounters on a page, on submit, it strips HTML from all `textarea`, `input` and `select` elements. I feel like I'm missing a basic trick.

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).find(':input')
    if (!isNaN(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value
            .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
            .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
            .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
            .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
            .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }
});
```

Comment: While it's good to be aware of HTML injection, I would do this server-side as well as it will be much more secure. It's trivial to get around any JS input validation.

Comment: Server-side is already accounted for. This is purely to give a more graceful error message.

Comment: Good news, carry on then :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the return value from `.find`. `this` will still refer to the form.

Two things you might want to consider:

- Use the descendant combinator to access the fields immediately:  `$('form :input')`
- The `val` setter handles iteration natively

Thus:

```
$('form :input').val(function() {
   return !isNaN(this.value) ? this.value : this.value.replace( ... );
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62otmvrm/)

Comment: Nice one on using `val`'s callback, so often overlooked (including by me).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you may let it do the encoding for you:

```
function htmlEncode(value){
    //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
    //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Then do:

```
$('form :input').val(function() {
   return this.value = htmlEncode(this.value);
});
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/5528759

See a demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/vbwt3828/

Hope it helps